# get the width of the particular component and increase it's width by some percentage of the current width using css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to increase the width of the html component(say text field) by some percentage of it's current width using CSS only.

Eg: current width = 10px;
New width should be  current width * 2.

can we achieve this using css?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/NejMF/109/

Comment: not like that...actually i have a webpage having multiple textbox,each having different width.i'm going to provide an option for the users to double the textfield's width. so, i need to know whether it is possible to double the width using CSS by calculating the current width of the text field and increase it's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your problem right its not possible only with css.
the only thing you can make is to enlarge your field when the user *focus the field itself*

like here for example the css:
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gcd6k1C8asGLPbGJIpfS?p=preview)

```
input[type=text] {


width: 100px;
  height:20px;
  -webkit-transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 250px;
  height:100px;
}
```

And the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  Search: <input type="text" name="search">
  </body>

</html>
```

If you want to enlarge your textfield if the user klicks on a button or something like that you have to use javascript. but its not difficult.